# Error when i try to create livewire component

Tags: laravel

I've installed laravel livewire on a Laravel 8 project, ad when i run the command `php artisan make:livewire table` the terminal shows this error:

```
ArgumentCountError 

  Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Str::finish(), 1 passed in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cuoreLaravel/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/helpers.php on line 12 and exactly 2 expected

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php:235
    231▕      * @param  string  $value
    232▕      * @param  string  $cap
    233▕      * @return string
    234▕      */
  ➜ 235▕     public static function finish($value, $cap)
    236▕     {
    237▕         $quoted = preg_quote($cap, '/');
    238▕ 
    239▕         return preg_replace('/(?:'.$quoted.')+$/u', '', $value).$cap;

      +17 vendor frames 
  18  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

I've followed all the documentation installation steps, but I don't understand what the problem is.
I hope someone can help me :-) thanks

Comment: Please don't edit titles to add 'solved'. Either add your own answer and accept it, or delete the question. Just saying you fixed it but not saying how offers nothing to future readers.

Comment: Ok, i'm sorry...thanks to the hint :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me after a fresh install of Livewire. Running php artisan optimize fixed it in my case. I have not found the exact reason, but I suspect some of the Livewire config needed to be included in the config cache first.

So either optimize, or clear the cached config completely.

Comment: Great, clearing config cache using `php artisan config:cache` command solved the issue.